# Order by distance through association with Geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, geocoding, rails-geocoder

I'm using the Geocoder gem in my project on my `Location` model which has one `Venue` and I want to search for the venues near a specified latitude and longitude and order them by their location distance. Right now I do my search like this:

```
location_ids = Location.near([lat, lng], 1, units: :km).map(&:id)
venues = Venue.where("location_id IN (?)", location_ids)
```

I know I can do `.map(&:venue)` and that would give me the venues directly but after this a query I chain in my controller, and doing that yields an `Array` and not an `ActiveRecord::Relation` which I can continue chaining queries on.

How can I get my venues ordered by the location distance?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think this does what you need - have not been able to try on geocoder directly so let me know:

```
locs = Location.near([lat, lng], 1, units: :km)
venues = Venue.joins(:location).merge(locs)
```

Comment: This works but it's not really what I need to do. Missed something in my question and I updated it.